# Find an element by id within a dynamically added control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, getelementbyid

I have an asp page in which I add dynamically a control I created (several times). In that control I have textbox for password and username and a revert button.

I use this javascript code in that control and it fails:

```
function HandlePasswordChanged() {
    document.getElementById("<%=btnRevert.ClientID %>").disabled = false;
}
function HandleUserChanged() {
    document.getElementById("<%=btnRevert.ClientID %>").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("<%=txtPassword.ClientID %>").disabled = false;
}
function btnRevertClick() {
    document.getElementById("<%=btnRevert.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("<%=txtPassword.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("<%=txtUsername.ClientID %>").value = document.getElementById("<%=systemAccount.ClientID %>").value;
    document.getElementById("<%=txtPassword.ClientID %>").value = "";
}
```

what it does is when I press the revert button on one control it disables the textbox on the other control - getelement fails to find the correct one.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Consider posting the rendered html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution.

The problem was that every time I added the acsx control with the javascript code it added multiple functions with the same name but the inside was different. when one control wanted to call its "own" function it just used the first one since they were all named the same.

My solution was to change the function from this:

```
function HandleUserChanged() {
    document.getElementById("<%=btnRevert.ClientID %>").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("<%=txtPassword.ClientID %>").disabled = false;
}
```

to this:

```
function HandleUserChanged(btnRevertId, txtPasswordId, cellPasswordId) {
    document.getElementById(btnRevertId).disabled = false;
    document.getElementById(txtPasswordId).disabled = false;
}
```

and then in the c# code I add this:

```
txtUsername.Attributes.Add("onchange", "HandleUserChanged(\"" + btnRevert.ClientID + "\", \"" + txtPassword.ClientID + "\", \"" + cellPassword.ClientID + "\")");
```

This way each control know exactly which controls belong to him and sends the correct parameters to the function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on .net 4.0:

You can set `ClientIDMode="Static"` for your dynamically added controls. Also, you have to make sure you set unique ids for your controls.

Comment: The control I add is an acsx I created and in it I have textboxes with static ids so when I add multiples of this acsx I do not have unique ids for the textboxes inside.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was driving me insane.